# outlook 2013 not updating folders

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2016, outlook-2013

I've recently set up a new Windows server 2016 RDS enviroment, and I've started some user testing.
One user has a problem in Outlook where folders will not update. If a new mail comes in he has to switch to a different folder and then back before it's visible. This is also the case if he deletes, moves, or marks an email. He has to switch to a different folder and back before it's visible.

I've tried setting up a new Outlook profile for him, tried setting up a new Windows user profile (by deleting his user profile disk), and I've tried switching cached exchange on and back off.
The problem dissapeared for a day when I started Outlook in safe mode, and then back to normal mode. But now, after logging off and on to the terminal server, the problem is back.

I have another test user in the same enviroment, and she is not experiencing any problems.
Both users have used Outlook 2013 on Windows 2008R2 for a long time, with the same Exchange accounts, without ever facing this problem.

Any tips for me?

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be the Teamviewer Meeting Add-in. Problem dissapeared after disabling it.

Comment: So glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue relates to corruption of the RoamingCache folder in AppData\Local which you simply need to delete, I’ve tried and tested successfully on multiple users.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I will test that if I ever encounter the problem again.